# How can I target the first item in a Drupal view?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views

I have a Drupal Views page that shows all the latest articles that were posted. I want to show case the latest article in a different div on it's own, and then have my loop with all the other articles.

This is my code for the loop, which is in the node--view.html.twig file -

```
    <div{{ attributes.addClass('col-4')}}>
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}">
        <h3>{{ node.label }}</h3>
        {% set text = content.body|render|striptags %}
        <p>{{ text|length > 100 ? text|slice(0, 120) ~ '...' : text }}</p>
        <a href="{{ url }}" class="btn black-btn">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and in my views-view-unformatted.html.twig file I have -

```
<h2>{{ view.getTitle() }}</h2>
  {% if title %}
      <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  {% endif %}
<div class="row news-row">
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class,
    ]
  %}
    {{- row.content -}}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) to determine which "item" is first/last in loop.

```
{% if loop.first %}
    ...
{% endif %}

{% if loop.last %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Your code

```
<div class="row news-row">
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class,
    ]
  %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        First item:
    {% endif %}

    {% if loop.first %}
        Last item:
    {% endif %}
    {{- row.content -}}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know where I would put that code? I tried as row.content.first in the views-view-unformatted.html.twig file but nothing shows up